# console.log("hello world!") showing me undefined in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log

I am recently started working on javascript. I opened firefox and type console.log("hello world") in console of firefox. and the output is 'undefined'. Very bad start...

[image]

Comment: You are trying to print the return value of `console.log()`, which is `undefined`. Just put `"hello world!"` and it would work.

Comment: The `<-` means it's the value your expression evaluated to. `console.log('hello world!')` doesn't return anything so it evaluates to `undefined`, but as side-effect it will print a log message. You did however hide log messages! If you click the "Logs (2)" button - which tells you that there were 2 log messages printed - you'll see them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to toggle the website's logs to be shown. Just click the `Logs (2)` in your screenshot and you will see every `console.log` output.

Comment: Isn't their screenshot showing logs tab already?